# What is the normal fashion for uploading files into EBS from local

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I've been researching how people are working with BOTO3 and AWS .. 
 [Putting data into EBS backed EC2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867400/putting-data-into-ebs-backed-ec2-instance)

So I have a running EC2 instance, it has a volume attached to it...

Should I programmatically download the volume and modify it?? or do I get the IP address, and then upload the file to a known path of the EBS via SSH?? RSync?

Seeing many options but want to perform what is best practice, especially with security in mind.

Do you download a snapshot and modify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I programmatically download the volume and modify it?

How would you even do that exactly? And if you did, how would you then push it back up to AWS as an EBS volume again?

> or do I get the IP address, and then upload the file to a known path
>   of the EBS via SSH?

That's the standard way.